# How to upload image PHP and insert path in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I'd like to include in my MySQL table a path to an image. The image path gets into the table by inserting the value of a "file" textfield (one of those Browse kind of deals). So the value that gets entered is something like: `image001.jpg`. But I can't seem to use that value to put an image into a html page. if it goes into the table fine, why can't I get it out?

I upload an image but I don't know where it's gone. Because there's no value entered in image field when I checked it through PhpMyadmin.

**Table schema**

```
CREATE TABLE employee_details
(
    emp_image varchar(255),
    employee_name varchar(50),
    employee_address varchar(50),
    employee_designation varchar(50),
    employee_salary int(),
);
```

**Query**

```
$sql="
    INSERT INTO employee_detail( 
        emp_image, 
        employee_name, 
        employee_address,
        employee_contact, 
        employee_designation, 
        employee_salary
    ) 
    VALUES( 
        '$_POST[emp_image]', 
        '$_POST[employee_name]',
        '$_POST[employee_address]', 
        '$_POST[employee_contact]',
        '$_POST[employee_designation]',
        '$_POST[employee_salary]'
    )";
```

Comment: post some code here..then you got some solution.

Comment: show your table and query

Comment: It's different to just set a filename / path into your database in comparison with uploading your file to a specific path.You have to do both.Make sure your file was uploaded and then you should check that you have the uploaded image path in your tb table.Simple upload tutorial can be found here: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Comment: firstly please find out my mistakes..Is their any error in my code?

Comment: [SQL Injections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Answer (score 11):

On your comment you ask how to upload and store the data to mysql. So here it is:

To get the file, you should have a script in your html like this:

```
<html>
<body>

     <form action="upload_file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <label for="file">Filename:</label>
        <input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
     </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Now, on POST, your PHP file should look like this but please take note that you have to check if the file exists on your POST:

```
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
  {
  echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
  }
else
  {
  echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
  echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
  echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
  echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];

  }
```

Since the "Stored in:" part is just the temporary path, you should move to your 'real' image path using [move_uploaded_file()](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp).
Let say the real/default path for your images is in:

```
$image_dir= '/images/';
```

You just have to move the file using this:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $image_dir. $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
```

And your full path to the image would be

```
$image = $final_save_dir . $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name'];
```

There are several ways to store the path to your database:

1st: Is to store just the **filename** and concatenate the path of the image in PHP using `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` and your default image path like:

```
$sql="insert into employee_detail( emp_image, employee_name, employee_address,
    employee_contact, employee_designation, employee_salary) 
values( '$image', '$_POST[employee_name]', '$_POST[employee_address]', '$_POST[employee_contact]',
    '$_POST[employee_designation]','$_POST[employee_salary]')";
```

2nd: Is to store the **full path** like:

```
$sql="insert into employee_detail( emp_image, employee_name, employee_address,
    employee_contact, employee_designation, employee_salary) 
values( '".$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."\\images\\".$image."', '$_POST[employee_name]', '$_POST[employee_address]', '$_POST[employee_contact]',
    '$_POST[employee_designation]','$_POST[employee_salary]')";
```

What I recommend is this approach wherein you will input the **partial path** (without the root dir) so that later you don't have a problem on deploying it:

```
$sql="insert into employee_detail( emp_image, employee_name, employee_address,
    employee_contact, employee_designation, employee_salary) 
values( 'images\\".$image."', '$_POST[employee_name]', '$_POST[employee_address]', '$_POST[employee_contact]',
    '$_POST[employee_designation]','$_POST[employee_salary]')";
```

And make sure that the images are successfully upload to that **default image dir/path**.

**UPDATE**

I also recommend that you use `mysqli_*` or `PDO` and use `prepare()` method /function to prevent sql injection.

Comment: please note that file uploads aren't stored in the `$_POST` array, but the `$_FILES` array.

Comment: Yes, thank you for pointing that out but you can store them in variables and store it to the database.

Comment: Are you kidding? Do you really want to insert raw data from $_POST into DB?

Comment: Ivan m new in php and am not kidding on this question.yes i opt this method .If i am wrong then please guide me..

Comment: Check my update. I include "how to upload" and "how to store". NP.

Answer (score 1):

If you upload an image, it is saved in the temporary path at first. You'll have to move it to your final directory, otherwise it'll be gone after script execution. What basically happens is this:

If you have a form with some form fields (text, checkbox, textarea, whatever), AND a file field (`<input type="file" name="uploaded_file" />`), all 'normal' fields will be accessible with the `$_POST` array. The file(s) however will be accessible in the `$_FILES` array (see also the [man page about file uploads](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php)).

Now when you receive the POST request, the uploaded files are stored in your temporary directory. If you don't do anything, it'll be deleted again after script execution. So you'd need to call the [move_uploaded_file() function](https://www.php.net/move_uploaded_file). Example:

```
$final_save_dir = '/path/to/images/dir/';
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $final_save_dir . $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
```

And your full path to the image would be

```
$image_full_path = $final_save_dir . $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name'];
```

This path can be saved in your database:

```
$sql="
INSERT INTO employee_detail( 
    emp_image, 
    ...
) 
VALUES( 
    '$image_full_path', 
    ...
)";
```

**IMPORTANT:** please take note on @brewal's comment. Your script is VERY unsafe like this.

Comment: It's confusing how the question asks: *How to insert image path in MySQL?"* different from *How to upload image and store path in MySQL?*

Comment: sorry i am new here and didn't know how to ask it properly.well you are right,now i clearly understand that i want to ask it as how to upload image and store path in Mysql... please suggest some views regards this question.